# Enlarge picture using Pillow package keep ratio

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use python pillow package to enlarge picture and here is my try

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('Sample.jpg')
new_image = image.resize((1080, 1080))
new_image.save('Output.jpg')
```

The code is working but the output image loses completely the ratio. How can I enlarge the image without losing the quality?

Comment: Do you want to keep the aspect ratio when enlarge the image?

Comment: I mean to keep the quality of the image after enlarging it.

Comment: You couldn't avoid losing the quality when enlarge an normal image.

Comment: so you mean there is no solution ??!!

Comment: To repair the quality: 1. Use AI to repair it. 2. Use vectorgraph instead of normal image.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is image upscaling, which is a more complex problem just than enlarging the image. I recommend looking into image upscaling packages. A lot of them use CNNs for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you guide me to a tutorial or a solution?